# Como identificar onde ocorrem as falhas que o Google Analytics me retorna?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-analytics-api

Estou recebendo pelo Google Analytics as seguintes falhas:

```
NullPointerException (@ViewGroup:dispatchDraw:2879) {main}
NullPointerException (@ViewGroup:dispatchDraw:2859) {main}
```

Mas não sei como identifico onde está ocorrendo estas falhas.

Comment: É só essas linhas que está aparecendo no **stacktrace** do GoogleAnalytics? Isso aparece na sessão **Comportamento** > **Falhas e exceções**? Como está fazendo esse track de erro?

Comment: sim em falhas e exceções, pois é não sei quero descobrir :/